# Unable to write, or read a sensor's registers. Do I have an error in my code?

Tags: sensors, i2c, wire-library

I'm trying to write to register the change some settings for a sensor I'm using (BNO055) and then read the same register to verify if the changes are successful.

However, the only value I'm able to read from the register is 1. Is the issue with my code or something to do with the sensor?

Thank you for your help. I've included what I think the relevant code is.

```
/**************************************************************************/
void write_register(uint8_t sensor_address, uint8_t register_address, uint8_t register_value) {
  wire_custom.beginTransmission (sensor_address);
  wire_custom.write(register_address);
  wire_custom.write(register_value);
  wire_custom.endTransmission ();
}

/**************************************************************************/
byte read_register(uint8_t sensor_address, uint8_t register_address, uint8_t bytes) {
  uint8_t result;
  wire_custom.beginTransmission (sensor_address);
  wire_custom.write(register_address);
  wire_custom.endTransmission ();
  wire_custom.requestFrom(sensor_address, bytes);
  result = wire_custom.read();
  return result;
}

/**************************************************************************/
void setup(void)
{
  wire_custom.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL, 400000);

  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!bno.begin())
  {
    Serial.print("Ooops, no BNO055 detected ... Check your wiring or I2C ADDR!");
    while (1);
  }
  delay(1000);
  bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);

  // updating range
  bno.setMode(Adafruit_BNO055::OPERATION_MODE_CONFIG);
  delay(1000);
  write_register (0x28, 0x0A, 0b00111000);
  // bno.setMode(Adafruit_BNO055::OPERATION_MODE_GYRONLY);
  delay(1000);
  register_1 = read_register (0x28, 0x0A, 1); 
}

/**************************************************************************/
void loop(void)
{
  sensor_calibration ();

  sensor_data (x_placeholder, y_placeholder);

  // printing register 1
  Serial.print(register_1);
  Serial.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the BNO055 but from the datasheet it looks like there are two register map pages (which can be changed via register #7) that can be either 0 (which is the default configuration at boot) or 1. The register you attempt to write (0x0A) is the low byte of the Y axis acceleration data (which presumably is read-only) when register page #0 (default) is selected or the Gyroscope configuration in page #1. Make sure the correct register page is selected.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I will experiment with this and update with the outcome.

Comment: Seems the setMode function from the library I'm using isn't working, so I will investigate that. Happy to accept the comment as an answer to the question, but isn't letting me. Thanks for your help.